# Text overflows the drop area slightly in the image uploader

Tags: bug, design, uploader

Please observe how the descenders on the text "to upload your image (max 2 MiB)" intersects with the dotted border and extends beyond the drop area in the screenshot below:

[image: screenshot of image uploader with overflowing text]

If I remember correctly, the drop area used to be larger and completely encompass the 'to upload your image (max 2 MiB)'. To be clear, the drop area is *working*; it just doesn't look as nice as it used to.

Tested on macOS (Firefox, Chrome and Safari) and Windows (Chrome, Edge).